# Linux configure web server port on linux

Tags: linux, playframework, webserver

I am running Play Framework on Linux and at the moment the URL is

```
http://www.example.net:9999
```

How do I change it to

```
http://www.example.net
```

I also want to run a ssh port

```
http://www.example.net:9443
```

Is this a linux configuration or is it on the web server? 
If its linux any relevant links would be helpful.

UPDATE
Following biesiors answer below I realised that by default if you set the port to 443 for ssh then you automatically get the url

```
https://www.example.net
```

which is equivalent to

```
https://www.example.net:443
```

This however still didn't work on my ec2 instance. Following some investigation and trial and error I found that if I started my web server with root then this port was available and worked. So now I just need to figure out the permissions.

So the answer is

> You need to be root (superuser) to bind to ports under 1024. That's why 9443 works, but 443 doesn't

So my question still stands at how do I run with port 9443 but have the url below and is it ok to run the webserver as root, it doesn't seem right

```
https://www.example.net
```

EDIT 2: 
So the answer is that you need to remap the ports in the the IP tables

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-port 9000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9443
```

Comment: Clarification: by `ssh port`, do you mean [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for `https` support? Because `ssh` does not apply to web servers.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is very wide... I just guess you have two possible solution:

1. Start your application using port `80` - if it's available
2. If you have some common web server working on port 80 (and want to keep it) you need to configure it to work as a [front-end HTTP server as described in the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the port 9443 instead of the default ssl port 443 for which you need to be a root or super user you will need to remap the ports in the iptables

For playframework the default port is 9000 and not 80 or 8080 so you need to remap that

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-port 9000
```

For the ssl port you need to map from 443 to 9443 so

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9443
```